# Why isn't my Django object saved to the database?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, model

I'm writing tests in a Django project and I've got some factories set up to create test content. I now have some trouble in which an email address isn't saved to the database:

```
device = DeviceFactory.create()
device.owner.email = 'a@b.c'
device.save()

print(device.owner.email)  # prints out 'a@b.c'
print(device.id)  # prints out 1
d = Device.objects.get(id=device.id)  # get the object from the DB again
print(d.owner.email)  # prints out jon.avery@ourcompany.com (or any other mock email address the factory creates)
```

Why does this not save the record to the database?

Answer (score 2):

**`email`** is associated with your **`Owner`** model, not **`Device`** model.So, You need to call the **`save()`** method of **`owner`**, not **`device`**

```
device.owner.email = 'a@b.c'
device.owner.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a simple solution, you should call `save` of your `owner` field because it is a different model that contains `email`.

```
device.owner.save()
```

But generally I would recommend you to override your `save` method of your `Device` model. So next time you won't have to remember that you must call `save` for internal fields.

```
class Device(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.owner.save()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    ...
```